# Woodchuck Cider w/Fox on bottle?

Tags: pairing, specialty-beers

A friend had a woodchuck cider with a picture of a fox on the bottle a while back and she keeps going on and on about how 'it was the best cider ever'. Anyone know which cider that is? I looked at their website, but the pictures do not show the labels themselves. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Can anyone confirm that Woodchuck does *not* have foxes on their labels?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't [Fox Barrel Cider](http://www.foxbarrel.com/)?

Comment: I havent had a chance to ask my friend yet (or rather she doesn't remember) so I need to go get an assortment and have cider tasting!

Comment: As far as I know, Woodchuck does not have any bottles with Foxes.

Comment: @anthony-arnold, after trying several, we found it! It was indeed a Fox Barrel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was likely a pear cider from the folks at Fox Barrel (http://www.foxbarrel.com/).

Comment: The specific one was their black berry cider, but it was indeed a foxbarrel.